# My JQuery show() works in IE but not FF?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, firefox

In my .Net web app, I have some elements with a class of "skmTooltipHost"  which are dynamically placed on a page.

When the mouse is hovered over them, a tool-tip kind of popup should display.  This is working perfectly in IE, but not at all in Firefox.

Please help!

The javascript which does the "On Hover and Show"

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".skmTooltipHost").hover(function () {
      $(this).empty().append('<div class="skmTooltipContainer"><strong>hello</strong>' + $(this).attr('tooltip') + '</div>');
      $(this).find('.skmTooltipContainer').css("left", $(this).position().left + 20);
      $(this).find('.skmTooltipContainer').css("top", $(this).position().top + $(this).height());
      $(".skmTooltipContainer").css("display", "inline-block");
      $(".skmTooltipContainer").show();
      $(this).show();
   },function () {    
     $(".skmTooltipContainer").fadeTo(500, 1.0, function () { $(this).remove(); });
   });
});
```

My CSS

```
.skmTooltipHost
{
cursor: help;
border-bottom: dotted 1px brown;

}

.skmTooltipContainer
{
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-top: 3px;
padding-bottom: 3px;
 display:inline-block;
position: absolute!important;
background-color: #ff9;
border: solid 1px #333;
z-index: 999;
}
```

**Edit**

I finally used a set of different but similar code which does work. I'm not sure what the difference is.  My working code is below:

```
 function simple_tooltip(target_items, name) {
      $(target_items).each(function (i) {
          $("body").append("<div class='" + name + "' id='" + name + i + "'><p>Click for a link to the run details</br><strong>Server:   </strong>" + $(this).attr('title') + "</br><strong>Information:</strong>" + $(this).attr('error') + "</p></div>");
          var my_tooltip = $("#" + name + i);

          $(this).removeAttr("title").mouseover(function () {
              my_tooltip.css({ opacity: 0.8, display: "none" }).fadeIn(100);
          }).mousemove(function (kmouse) {
              my_tooltip.css({ left: kmouse.pageX + 15, top: kmouse.pageY + 15 });
          }).mouseout(function () {
              my_tooltip.fadeOut(100);
          });
      });
  }
  $(document).ready(function () {
      simple_tooltip($(".skmTooltipHost"), "tooltip");
  });



.tooltip{
position:absolute;
z-index:999;
left:-9999px;
background-color:#dedede;
padding:2px;
border:1px solid #fff;
width:250px;
```

}

```
.tooltip p{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    color:black;
    background-color:white;
    padding:2px 7px;
}
```

Comment: Actually, these 2 lines don't do anything right now, I just added them to try. They don't seem to impact the functionality at all. Still works in IE. Not in FF.  $(".skmTooltipContainer").css("display", "inline-block");

$(this).show();

Comment: Have you tried adding positioning to your `.skmTooltipHost` (e.g. `position: relative;`)?

Comment: try using `.on` to trigger the `hover`.

Comment: When I trace through in FF, the hover event is being called correctly.    @MassivePenguin  I've tried adding that.  This seems to break the functionality in IE but not change FF

Comment: If the event is being called correctly, and you're not seeing any JS errors, my guess (unless you can show us a JSFiddle, a guess is the best I can do) is that it's a CSS issue.

Comment: I think its CSS too but I can't think of anything else to try. I tried to throw some !important flags but didn't get any results. Maybe I didn't do the right combination.

Comment: Which version oj jQuery you are using? It's working fine under 1.9.1 to 1.6.4  http://jsfiddle.net/T7FeD/

Comment: 1.8.1 , but I tried some earlier versions before posting the question. @Morpheus

Comment: Not sure if FF is not liking the lack of space after the "!" here: `position: absolute!important;`

Comment: Which version of FF you are on?

Comment: @okyanet I tried position: absolute! important; and position: absolute !important; with no obvious change in either broswer

Comment: @mplace I'm on 19.0.2, maybe this is the problem.

Comment: @Morpheus Its a good thought. Its difficult for me to install the latest FF version on my development box, but I was able just now to Install the latest version of Chrome, (which I haven't tested yet), and this is acting just like FF,  nothing displayed during hover

Comment: @mplace is my example of fiddle is working on your machine?

Comment: @Morpheus  Yes--- in the same FF browser.  Does this mean CSS?

Comment: @mplace yes, something else is causing to not work. Take a look at developer tools and see if there are more styles applied to your tooltip div.

Comment: @Morpheus I'm looking but so far didn't find anything.  The point which generates the hover is a datapoint on a Chart created from the .net libraries.    Thanks for the help so far. I'll keep playing with it.

Answer (score 1):

Is [this (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/ab4ML/1/) the CSS/HTML/JS you’re using? This works for me in Chrome and Firefox. This line probably doesn’t do what you want though:

```
$(".skmTooltipContainer").fadeTo(500, 1.0, function () { $(this).remove(); });
```

Comment: The Css / HTML is the same, but the HTML is more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem as I see it is in those lines :

This line marks the span for removal from the DOM.
Thus it disappear and you dont hover the control anymore.

```
$(this).empty().append('<div class="skmTooltipContainer"><strong>hello</strong>' + $(this).attr('tooltip') + '</div>');
```

This line removes a control from the DOM. You would think this refers to the tooltip, but in fact, it refers to the top SPAN (or tooltip host in your case).

```
$(".skmTooltipContainer").fadeTo(500, 1.0, function () { $(this).remove(); });
```

This code proved to work :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".skmTooltipHost").hover(function () {
      $(this).append('<div class="skmTooltipContainer"><strong>hello</strong>' + $(this).attr('tooltip') + '</div>');
      $(this).find('.skmTooltipContainer').css("left", $(this).position().left + 20);
      $(this).find('.skmTooltipContainer').css("top", $(this).position().top + $(this).height());
      $(".skmTooltipContainer").css("display", "inline-block");
      $(".skmTooltipContainer").show();
      $(this).show();
   },function () {    
     $(".skmTooltipContainer").fadeTo(500, 1.0, function () { $(".skmTooltipContainer").remove(); });
   });
});
```

You can test it here : http://jsfiddle.net/ab4ML/2/

Mention to [moeffju](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358063/my-jquery-show-works-in-ie-but-not-ff/15361593#15361593) for providing the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the great feedback. I ended up using another solution, which I'll post below....but this helps me understand the code.